# Passing parameter from a button to android:onClick method

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

Hi I have something like this (3 buttons) in my activity xml pointing to same method:

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button_1"
        android:onClick="printNo"
        android:text="@string/Button_1" />
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button_2"
        android:onClick="printNo"
        android:text="@string/Button_2" />

 <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button_3"
        android:onClick="printNo"
        android:text="@string/Button_3" />
```

Is there any way I could determine which button was pressed while in the printNo method ?

Comment: why you are using this way.. Also possible to call in java file dynamically..

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
public void printNo( View v ) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case (R.id.Button_1):
        //stuff
    break;
    case (R.id.Button_2):
        //stuff
    break;
    case (R.id.Button_3):
        //stuff
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

As @user1106018 said - you can use `tag` in xml like that:

```
<Button android:onClick="f" android:tag="0"/>
```

Then it is really simple to get this tag in this way:

```
public void f(View v) {
    String value =  v.getTag(); 
}
```

Comment: Just missing a cast since getTag() returns an Object not a String

Comment: or `Integer.parseInt((String)v.getTag())` for an integer

Answer (score 14):

Simply switch over the ID:

```
public void printNo(View v){
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.Button_1:
        break;
    case R.id.Button_2:
        break;
    case R.id.Button_3:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Working in my end

```
public void printNo(View v) {

switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.Button_1:
    break;

    case R.id.Button_2:
    break;

    case R.id.Button_3:
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In xml add tag, np with name of button.

```
public void printNo(View V){
    view.getTag();
    // now you can recognize view with getTag()
}
```

Other answers seems also good;)